# Function for these parse elements will do not repeat. BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

Which function(or etc) is ideal so that these nicknames do not repeat on my parser. Dont know how to do that. I'l be very grateful if you help me.

Source:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# save all the nicknames to 'CSV' file format
filename = "BattlePassNicknames.csv"
f = open(filename, "a", encoding="utf-8")
headers1 = "Member of JAZE Battle Pass 2019\n"
b = 1
if b < 2:
    f.write(headers1)
    b += 1
# start page
i = 1
while True:
    # disable jaze guard. turn off html 'mod_security'
    link = 'https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page='+str(i)
    my_url = Request(
        link,
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    )
    i += 1  # increment page no for next run
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    if uClient.url != link:
        break
    page_html = uClient.read()
    # Check if there was a redirect
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # grabs each name of player
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-area"})

    for container in containers:
        playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
        print("BattlePass PlayerName: " + playerName)
        f.write(playerName + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all the names to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

```
my_set = set()
# Lets add some elements to a set
my_set.add('a')
my_set.add('b')
print(my_set)  # prints {'a', 'b'}
# Add one more 'a'
my_set.add('a')
print(my_set) # still prints {'a', 'b'} !
```

In your case, let's add all the names to a set and then write to the file after the for loop.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# save all the nicknames to 'CSV' file format
filename = "BattlePassNicknames.csv"
f = open(filename, "a", encoding="utf-8")
headers1 = "Member of JAZE Battle Pass 2019\n"
b = 1
if b < 2:
    f.write(headers1)
    b += 1
# start page
i = 1
names = set()
while True:
    # disable jaze guard. turn off html 'mod_security'
    link = 'https://jaze.ru/forum/topic?id=50&page='+str(i)
    my_url = Request(
        link,
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    )
    i += 1  # increment page no for next run
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    if uClient.url != link:
        break
    page_html = uClient.read()
    # Check if there was a redirect
    uClient.close()
    # html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # grabs each name of player
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "top-area"})

    for container in containers:
        playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
        names.add(playerName)

for name in names:
    f.write(name + "\n")
f.close()
```

**EDIT**

Sets do not preserve the order. If you want to retain the order, just use lists.

```
...
names = []
while True:
...
    for container in containers:
        playerName = container.div.a.text.strip()
        if playerName not in names:
            names.append(playerName)

for name in names:
    f.write(name + "\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: It works thanks! But he mixed all the names, and the guy which was the first, has become to 44 position. Why and how to fix?